# I am solving a programming quiz and I am not able to understand the logic behind line 10 of this code

Tags: c, algorithm

This is a codechef quiz. the first line takes input of letters that are known. The second input takes in the number of inputs and for each word given later we have to perform operation whether the string can be generated by known letters or not. I am not able to understand why in `line 10` the integer array latin with index of `s[i]-97` is assigned to 1. can anyone explain?

```
int main(void) 
{

    int latin[26] = {0};
    int n, i, j, flag;
    char s[26], w[12];

    scanf ("%s", s);
    for (i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    latin[s[i]-97] = 1;

    scanf ("%d", &n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf ("%s", w);
        flag = 0;
        for (j=0; j<strlen(w); j++)
        {
            if (latin[w[j]-97] != 1)
            {
                printf ("No\n");
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag == 0)
        printf ("Yes\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: About the subtraction with `97`, you should check an [ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) it might become clearer. Look for the lower-case `'a'`, and think about what you would get if you did e.g. `'c' - 'a'`. This is also the reason one should not use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) when coding.

Comment: I think that 1 is used at random... it's only a filler, to check whether the content has been altered or not, later. Check the part `if (latin[w[j]-97] != 1)`

Comment: As for the assignment, see that comparison `latin[w[j]-97] != 1` later in the code? If you really want to understand what the code does, then build it with debug information, and then step through the code in a debugger, line by line.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg is it really related with ASCII code anyway? Any other value that 1, like 2 or 3 should also work, unless it's in the range of printable elements, right?

Comment: What @JoachimPileborg said. Plus, it's a *terrible* introduction to `C`.

Comment: Am I misreading the question? Is is not like that the question targets to the assignment of `1`, rather subtraction of 97 from `s[i]`.... or am I missing something here?

Comment: @SouravGhosh The subtraction is all about ASCII. It will also fail if the input contains anything but lower-case letters. The assignment could be any arbitrary `int` value that is non-zero, as long as it matches the comparison later in the code.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The question can be read as `why -97` or `why 1`. I don't see one interpretation being blatantly more obvious than the other.

Comment: @dxiv Then, let's ask op for clarification. :) [Voted to close unless clarified]

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question._

Comment: BTW, do not write code like this. :)  It does many unsafe things.  It is likely to have crashes, and have security problems.

Comment: When you encounter code that is difficult to understand like that, make sure you learn the following from it: That is a *bad example* of how to write code.

Answer (score 1):

`latin` is an array that tells me whether a letter is known. For example:

```
latin[0] == 1; //letter 'a' is known
latin[3] == 0; //letter 'd' is unknown
```

Initially, all letters are unknown. If letter 'd' is known:

```
latin['d'-97] = 1; //letter 'd' is set to be known
//'d' has the ascii value of 100, thus 'd' - 97 equals 3.
```

To check whether a string `w` is valid, the program loops through each letter in the string, and if the there is a letter that is unknown, the string is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

97 is the ASCII code for letter `a` so by removing 97 it converts a to 0, b to 1 etc...

If you ask about assignment, it a value to compare with
`latin[w[j]-97] != 1`

Comment: umm... i think the question was `why in line 10 the integer array latin with index of s[i]-97 is assigned to 1`.. not why subtract 97.

Comment: ... not sure but as it might be I edited my answer to complete it.

Comment: Still not very clear whether the `1` has a specific meaning or not, but fair enough. removing my DV.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you enter "abcd", that becomes 's'

The letter 'a' in the ascii table is 97.
So 'a' - 97 = 0, 'b' - 97 = 1 etc.

So latin[0], latin[1], latin[2], latin[3] all become 1, meaning you have typed an 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'..

Then a new string is entered into w and the next for loop checks if the newly entered characters were entered into 's' too.

```
for (j=0; j<strlen(w); j++)
  if (latin[w[j]-97] != 1) // here!
```

So if you enter bcda the second time it will print "Yes" but if you enter bbcd or abee it will print "no" as you typed at least one character differently

Answer (score 0):

Acually array of length h stores elements at location 0 to n-1. there are 26 character from a to z. you declare array

```
 int latin[26] = {0};
```

it means size of latin is 26 and having 0 at location from 0 to 25.

```
 for (i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
 latin[s[i]-97] = 1;
```

the moto of latin[s[i]-97]=1 we are going consider letter a represent  position 0 , letter b represent position 1 and so on ... letter z represent  position z;

for all character in you your s latin contains 1;
after executing this loop.

then you are reading another word and pick each character one by one and checking value of location represent by this character if value is not equal to zero it means no .it all character of words having value equal to yes then flag will be have value 1 it means we will get yes.

Answer (score 0):

The design idea seems to be to use the `latin` array as a flag-array. That is - each element in `latin` tells you whether a specific letter is part of the first input string.

```
int latin[26] = {0};   // Initialize all elements to zero

scanf ("%s", s);       // Read a string (and pray that input is only letters)

for (i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
     latin[s[i]-97] = 1;    // Set the flags to 1 for each input letter, i.e.
                            // if input contains 'a' latin[0] becomes 1
                            // if input contains 'b' latin[1] becomes 1
                            // and so on
```

So the idea seem to be that after the loop, you can use `latin` to know which letters were present in the input. For instance - if `latin[3]` is still 0, you know there was no `c` in the input.

The code is full of potential UB and needs a major rewrite.

One example:

```
scanf ("%s", s);             // Potential overflow -> may cause UB
for (i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    latin[s[i]-97] = 1;      // s[i] may be less than 97 -> UB
                             // s[i] may be greaterthan than 122 -> UB
```

At least fix it like:

```
scanf ("%25s", s);           // Set upper limit for characters read
for (i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    if (s[i] >= 97 && s[i] <= 122) // Check before use
        latin[s[i]-97] = 1;
    else
        // Error handling (or just ignore)
```